# Why is my subdivision modifier not applying to my render ? You can see it is enabled for renders

Tags: rendering, modifiers, subdivision-surface

In the viewport, you can see the cake is smooth and it has a subdivision modifier with a viewport level of 5. The icon to allow it in renders is checked, yet it doesn't seem to work when I do a render. [image]

[image]

Comment: Suggestion.  Make the render number the same as the view number. Both can be 5.  That may be an easy experiment/solution for you to perform

Comment: because in the *Subdivision Modifier*, you set the viewport to have 5 subdivision level but only have set it to 2 in the final render. change it to 5 as well. but your subdivision level of 5 is too high, you can just use 2 and then right click and do a *Shade Smooth* so you don't have too many polygons

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Now that I see it, this makes perfect sense. Thanks